# Prepending/appending Razor views and sections with comments when using layouts (ASP.NET MVC 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My razor views are stored in a database and provided to the site via a VirtualPathProvider. Given certain flags, the service which returns them will, for debugging purposes, demarcate the beginning and end of each view with HTML comments including extra debugging information (caching, versioning, authorship, etc.) When using layouts, only the outermost layout view will include this information; in child layouts/views, the HTML comments including the information are not in a @section so never make it to the response. I'd want these comments to appear before the first rendered section, at least, but before and after each rendered section would be great.

I wonder if there's a clean way to do this anyone can think of or has had success with. If it matters, I'm using a custom view base type, so can override any relevant methods, and I'm willing to override the view engine.

What I currently see:

```
<!-- start of 'layout1' -->
entire html response
<!-- end of 'layout1' -->
```

What I'd optimally like to see:

```
<!-- start of 'layout1' -->
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- start of 'layout2' section 'section1' -->
      <div id="header">
        <!-- start of 'view1' section 'section2' -->
          <h1>hello!</h1>
        <!-- end of 'view1' section 'section2' -->
      </div>
    <!-- end of 'layout2' section 'section1' -->
  </body>
</html>
<!-- end of 'layout1' -->
```

Comment: You might want to give an example of what your desired html looks like and what it is looking like now with your current attempt.  Mainly because you want to "include metadata" which html has metadata tags, but you mention "HTML comments", so it sounds like you are not referring to metadata tags but instead some other scheme of including metadata.

Comment: AaronLS - thanks, updated.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm following you correctly, you just need those comments added at the beginning and end of each view? That's pretty simple if your custom view base is inheriting from WebViewPage.

```
public class MyViewBase<T> : WebViewPage<T> 
{
    public override void ExecutePageHierarchy()
    {
        WriteLiteral("<!-- Started Layout -->");
        base.ExecutePageHierarchy();
        WriteLiteral("<!-- Ended Layout -->");
    }
}
```

Note that this will get kinda noisy if you have various editor or display templates that all use the same custom base class.

Comment: Thanks. With this I'm getting the same as the "What I currently see" example. One comment at the beginning of the response, one at the end.

Comment: Each of your views will have to inherit from that base class in order for it to work on partials and what not. If you want all of your views to inherit from the custom class, you can do that from the Views/web.config. Just look for the <pages pageBaseType> section in there. If you only want it to happen for some views and not others, I'm not sure what to do there

Comment: pageBaseType is what I'm using, and threw a breakpoint in the base's constructor to verify it was being instantiated for each view. Haven't tried with partials, but I assume it will work there, just not with the main view and its layout chain.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can start from here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/05/defining-default-content-for-a-razor-layout-section.aspx
http://yingbiao.blogspot.com/2010/12/dive-deep-into-aspnet-mvc-razor-view.html

http://forums.asp.net/p/1815167/5029823.aspx?Re%20In%20razor%20master%20viewpage%20how%20to%20get%20a%20list%20of%20defined%20rendered%20sections%20

Also, I think for such customization you will need to define one more SectionWriter delegate.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I'll have to dig in to hacking Razor and figure this out on my own. These are good resources, have a delicious bounty.

Comment: Thanks Dan! Hope  this helps. Please post you own solution later, it's interesting topic.