# Inject comment with partial name during RenderPartial - asp.net razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

mvc4, razor viewengine. It would be useful if, when in debug mode, a snippet like this that includes a partial would leave a comment saying what partial it injected. Are there extensibility points that I just can't find? Obviously I could just type out this comment in the partial views, but that sounds like WAAYY too much work and isn't fun for anybody.

index.cshtml

```
<div class="somecontainer">
    @foreach(var thing in Model.Things) {
        Html.Partial("ThingPartial",thing)
    }
</div>
```

ThingPartial.cshtml

```
@model ThingModel
<h1>@Model.Name<h1>
<p>@Model.Description</p>
```

would generate html like this

```
<!--razorView:things/index-->
<div class="somecontainer">
  <!--partialView:ThingPartial-->
  <h1>Name 1<h1>
  <p>Description 1</p>

  <!--partialView:ThingPartial-->
  <h1>Name 2<h1>
  <p>Description 2</p>

  <!--partialView:ThingPartial-->
  <h1>Name 3<h1>
  <p>Description 3</p>
</div>
```

**Motivation**
I want my testers to be able to use the comments to write more accurate bug reports without my developers / me having to do anything extra!

What I have in my mind is something configurable in global.asax.cs, like so

```
  ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
  RazorViewEngine viewEngineToAdd = new RazorViewEngine();
  //I COMPLETELY MADE THIS LINE UP, THESE THINGS DON'T EXIST (but I want them to!
  viewEngineToAdd.PreRender += (OutputStream,IView) => OutputStream.Write(@"<!--"+IView.Name+"-->")
  ViewEngines.Engines.Add(viewEngineToAdd);
```

Comment: Found it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188985/prepending-appending-razor-views-and-sections-with-comments-when-using-layouts?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="somecontainer">
    @foreach(var thing in Model.Things) {
        Html.Raw("<!--" + thing + "-->");
        Html.Partial("ThingPartial",thing)
    }
</div>
```

Comment: I'll give you an upvote, but that is basically the same as manually writing it out in the partials. I want my testers to be able to use the comments to write more accurate bug reports without my developers / me having to do anything extra!

Comment: @scaryman: what kind of answer are you expecting then? If you want to generate output you'll have to actually define this output somewhere. This is only written in one place, I'd say that's not very elaborate.

Comment: extensibility points in the razor view engine - something that I could configure in code in global.asax.cs maybe. I'll add a mockup of what I want in the question.

Comment: and yeah, it's only in one place, but this is a contrived example. My actual code base has ~50 partials and ~20 views

Comment: @scaryman: I can't help you with the mockup but you could just make a method `Html.AdvancedPartial` that calls `Html.Raw` and `Html.Partial` with the provided arguments. That way you can call it everywhere like you would call `Html.partial` now.